# contents from fopen in typo3 and special characters

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, typo3

I have recently upgraded my typo3-installation. The new version is running utf8 only.
My old installation used iso8859-1. It is not possible to revert back to my old charset unfortunately...

I have a script which loads in data from another server via :

```
$handle = fopen("www.my-url.com/myloader.php", "r");
 if ($handle) {
    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
        }
    fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
```

my problem now is that danish-special-characters are not translated properly.
I have tried both utf8_encode & decode on $contents but neither works.
I cannot change the script on the other server as it is provider for many other sites which still has the old typo3-install running.

Comment: Example of the code source of your remote script could help to define the encoding. Or the real url, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a GET argument in myloader.php that specifies what charset the result should be encoded in. Default to ISO 8859-1 and use iconv to translate to UTF-8 as required, or vice versa.